# 'pot' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Well when I try to use my def getLotteryGame() in my Point.py it keeps telling me

```
'pot' refernced before assignment.
```

This is the code:

```
pot = 1

class Point:

    def buyLottery(name, amount):
       Point.startPoint(name)
       amount = int(amount)
       multiplier = random.randint(amount, 217)
       pot = int(pot+multiplier)
       if name not in players:
          if Point.getCost(name, amount) == True:
             players.append(name)
             return "%s has joined the the lottery for %s P$ which magically grew to %s P$!" % (name.title(), Point.amountCost(name, amount, multiplier)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
pot = int(pot+multiplier)
```

You are using `pot` even before assigning any value in it. If you want to use the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) `pot`, then you need to explicitly tell Python, like this

```
def buyLottery(name, amount):
    global pot
    ...
    pot = int(pot+multiplier)
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Yeah I never really used objects outside of class before.

Comment: So if i use another object outside of class like lotteryStart = time.time() would I need to global that as well?

Comment: @user3103923 If you are going to change `lotteryStart` in the function, then you have to `global` that as well. If you are simply accessing it, you don't need to `global` it